# How can i configure a kafka batch consumer to retry a pre-defined no of times using SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka '2.2.7.RELEASE' to create a batch consumer and I'm trying to understand How can i configure a kafka batch consumer to retry a pre-defined no of times using SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler?

I see the one of the SeekToCurrentErrorHandler constructors takes 'maxFailures' as an argument but I don't see any such option for  SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.2.x is no longer supported.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh)  for the reasons why recovery after some number of failures is not supported with batch listeners and older versions of the framework.

You can use the `RetryingBatchErrorHandler` (since 2.3.7) or `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` (since 2.5.0) instead.